# Can I use a temporary 2D-array to avoid data dependency in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a piece of code like this:

```
int n=5;
Eigen::VectorXd vec(n);
vec.setZero();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    int idx = i%n;
    vec(idx)+=(i/n);
}
std::cout<<vec<<endl;
```

I would like to parallelize it.

I figure out a method to avoid data dependency.

```
int n=5;
int num_thread = 6;
omp_set_num_threads(num_thread);
Eigen::MatrixXd mat(num_thread,n);
mat.setZero();
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    int idx_pool = omp_get_thread_num();
    int idx_col = i%n;
    mat(idx_pool,idx_col)+=(i/n);
}
Eigen::VectorXd vec(n);
vec = mat.rowwise().sum();
std::cout<<vec<<endl;
```

I'm wondering that is this method right?

Comment: Do you have some test which measures performance? In many cases adding threads leads to pessimization. Are you sure that [Eigen underneath](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/TopicMultiThreading.html) doesn't do some parallelization, so it would be enough just use some ready function from Eigen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real code has a much higher workload in the parallel loop, this is quite a valid approach (and if the workload is low, the parallelization in itself may be pointless). The state-of-art method would be to use a reduction (as mentioned by @VictorEijkhout), but it can be cumbersome if you have to define a custom one (and without obvious perf improvement depending on the case). Apart in some specific cases I don't think the memory issue is real one: when using a reduction, the threads have hidden private copies of the reducted variables/arrays anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have solved the race condition problem, but you have multiplied the memory demands of your program. You have also introduced a non-parallel operation: the `rowwise().sum()`, which decreases your performance gains.

Since you're doing a sort of reduction, you can use the OpenMP `reduction` clause, if the `+` operator is overloaded for the `VectorXd` class. Is it? Otherwise maybe you can define that yourself.